# LinkedIn API on localhost gives API key invalid

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

I'm working with the LinkedIn API on my localhost, using port 80. I get "API Key is invalid".

How do I get my API key to be valid?

I call the LinkedIn API from locally served pages with these URLS. I've added both URLs to "Javascript API domains" on the [LinkedIn API admin page](https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer).

```
http://myjobsite/index.php/test
http://myjobsite/index.php/my-second-test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing localhost to your local IP in the API page and then make a call using your IP.
Also ensure your API key IS correct, and that you Oauth User Agreement scope is what you want it to be able to access.